# Fedora touchpad drivers not working on lenovo laptop

Tags: fedora, fedora-33

I got a new lenovo laptop, installed fedora 33 but the touchpad seems not to working. I have connected it to an external mouse (its working) but I'm not comfortable.

I have installed synaptics using dnf:

```
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-drv-synaptics -y
```

But it does not do anything.

Comment: You're in the wrong place. StackOverflow is for programming questions only and https://superuser.com is for generic computer stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Fedora 35 Beta. There it should work.

Mouse point ok
Scrolling with two fingers ok
three fingers ok
left click ok

right click,  works with a two finger click.

Comment: I installed fedora 35 Beta and unfortunately there's no change

Comment: Did you try fedora 35 beta directly from a usb stick?

Comment: yes, I did but the touchpad drivers are still not working, i'm currently using a mouse

Comment: I had the same problem with Fedora 35 just now on T440s. Just upgrading the bios seems to have solved it.